# splitViewController collapseSecondary only fires at launch

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I’m working on an app that is misbehaving. The app has a splitViewController which, on first launch, fires the :

```
    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

function. However after rotating to landscape and back to portrait, it never fires again (and subsequently is showing my detail view instead of the master view which is not what I want). I’ve set the splitViewController.delegate to self… Can anyone give me some clues on what I should look more closely at to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found out my own answer. In this case in our `detailViewController` in `viewDidLoad()` we had assigned `splitViewController?.delegate = self` (why, I'm not sure at this point - the code is somewhat old). Removing this made the `collapseSecondary` function fire off as expected. Hope this helps someone.